# $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{6^k}{\left(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}\right)\left(3^k-2^k\right)} $ as a rational number.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{6^k}{\left(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}\right)\left(3^k-2^k\right)} $$

I know from the ratio test it convergest, and I graph it on wolfram alpha and I suspect the sum is 2; however, I am having trouble with the manipulation of the fraction to show the rational number.

ps. When it says write as a rational number it means to write the value of $S_{\infty}$ or to rewrite the fraction?

Comment: This is because the infinite sum is rational

Comment: @Amr Thanks, that is what I suspected.  The limiting sum is 2, correct?

Comment: I did not evaluate it. you can try evaluating it.

Comment: @Amr I tried with my calculator but it failed, and wolfram alpha just gave me a graph which showed that it was approaching 2.  Don't know how else to evaluate a sum other than those two listed, both didn't give me a number.

Comment: Why ?? After you use the method of diffrences you can show that $S_n=2-\frac{2^{n+1}}{3^{n+1}-2^{n+1}}$. Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n$

Comment: @amr Sorry, I was a bit unclear, I didn't know about the method of differences till you told me, and I was talking about how to just type in a sum and have a computer tell you the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That denominator should suggest the possibility of splitting the general term into partial fractions and getting a telescoping series of the form

$$\sum_{k\ge 1}\left(\frac{A_k}{3^k-2^k}-\frac{A_{k+1}}{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}}\right)\;,$$

where $A_k$ very likely depends on $k$. Note that if this works, the sum of the series will be

$$\frac{A_1}{3^1-2^1}=A_1\;.$$

Now

$$\frac{A_k}{3^k-2^k}-\frac{A_{k+1}}{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}}=\frac{3^{k+1}A_k-3^kA_{k+1}-2^{k+1}A_k+2^kA_{k+1}}{(3^k-2^k)(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}\;,$$

so you want to choose $A_k$ and $A_{k+1}$ so that

$$3^{k+1}A_k-3^kA_{k+1}-2^{k+1}A_k+2^kA_{k+1}=6^k\;.$$

The obvious things to try are $A_k=2^k$, which makes the last two terms cancel out to leave $3^{k+1}2^k-3^k2^{k+1}=6^k(3-2)=6^k$, and $A_k=3^k$, which makes the first two terms cancel out and leaves $6^k(3-2)=6^k$; both work.

**However**, summing $$\sum_{k\ge 1}\left(\frac{A_k}{3^k-2^k}-\frac{A_{k+1}}{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}}\right)\tag{1}$$ to $$\frac{A_1}{3^1-2^1}=A_1$$ is valid **only** if

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{A_k}{3^k-2^k}=0\;,$$

since the $n$-th partial sum of $(1)$ is

$$A_1-\frac{A_{n+1}}{3^{n+1}-2^{n+1}}\;.$$

Checking the two possibilities, we see that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2^k}{3^k-2^k}=0,\quad\text{but}\quad\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{3^k}{3^k-2^k}=1\;,$$

so we must choose $A_k=2^k$, and the sum of the series is indeed $A_1=2$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** $$\frac{6^k}{(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})(3^k-2^k)}=\frac{2^k}{(3^k-2^k)}-\frac{2^{k+1}}{(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}$$

Now use the method of diffrences.

Comment: fyi, a small typo, differences.  Thanks for the hint, and for giving the name of the method, greatly helps on learning the technique to have a name to search for.