# How to solve : $\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \frac{6^k}{(3^k-2^k)(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to find the sum of this : 
$$
\sum^{\infty}_{k=1} \dfrac{6^k}{(3^k-2^k)(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}
$$

I tried to find the partial fraction of this but I think this is wrong method ...please suggest how to proceed thanks.......

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319400/sum-limits-k-1-infty-frac6k-left3k1-2k1-right-left3k-2

Answer (score 6):

In fact, partial fractions is the way to go: Note that $$\frac{6^k}{(3^k-2^k)(3^{k+1}-2^{k+1})}=\frac{2^k}{3^k-2^k}-\frac{2^{k+1}}{3^{k+1}-2^{k+1}}, $$
so that the series is telescopic.