# How to evaluate the series: $ \frac {20} {(5-4)(5^2-4^2)} + \frac {20^2} {(5^2-4^2)(5^3-4^3)} + \frac {20^3} {(5^3-4^3)(5^4-4^4)} + \ldots $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to evaluate this infinte summation?
$$ \dfrac {20} {(5-4)(5^2-4^2)} + \dfrac {20^2} {(5^2-4^2)(5^3-4^3)} + \dfrac {20^3} {(5^3-4^3)(5^4-4^4)} + \ldots $$

Telescopic cancellation is the way to go, I feel, but I don't know how to get this into telescopic form.

Hints?

Comment: Often when you have a fraction of the form $\frac{x}{bc}$ you can decompose it into a sum of fractions of the form $\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}$.  Here you have a sum of fractions of the first form; I'd try putting them into the second form and see what happens.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462070/how-to-solve-sum-infty-k-1-frac6k3k-2k3k1-2k1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice that:
$$\frac{20^k}{(5^k-4^k)(5^{k+1}-4^{k+1})}=\frac{4^k}{5^k-4^k}-\frac{4^{k+1}}{5^{k+1}-4^{k+1}},$$
in order to prove that:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{20^k}{(5^k-4^k)(5^{k+1}-4^{k+1})} = 4.$$

Comment: Amazing! As MJD said, I tried to bring it in this form...but I couldn't. This is awesome :D

Comment: Note also that $\frac {x^k}{y^k-x^k}-\frac {x^{k+1}}{y^{k+1}-x^{k+1}}=(y-x)\frac {(xy)^k}{(y^k-x^k)(y^{k+1}-x^{k+1})}$

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$
\frac{20}{(5−4)(5^2−4^2)}=\frac{4}{5-4}-\frac{4^2}{5^2-4^2}
$$
$$
\frac{20^2}{(5^2−4^2)(5^3−4^3)}=\frac{4^2}{5^2-4^2}-\frac{4^3}{5^3-4^3}
$$
$$
\frac{20^3}{(5^3−4^3)(5^4−4^4)}=\frac{4^3}{5^3-4^3}-\frac{4^4}{5^4-4^4}
$$

Means for gathering data through equations have

$$
\frac{20}{(5−4)(5^2−4^2)}+\frac{20^2}{(5^2−4^2)(5^3−4^3)}+\frac{20^3}{(5^3−4^3)(5^4−4^4)}+\cdots
$$
$$
=\frac{4}{5-4}-\frac{4^2}{5^2-4^2}+\frac{4^2}{5^2-4^2}-\frac{4^3}{5^3-4^3}+\frac{4^3}{5^3-4^3}-\frac{4^4}{5^4-4^4}+\cdots=\frac{4}{5-4}=4
$$

Comment: $4/(5-4)\neq1$, does it?

Comment: For trivial corrections like that, you can just edit the post yourself.